# Should I add a confirm password field in android?

Tags: java, android, authentication, password-confirmation

I am new to android, and I just started making a signup activity for my app. I found a number of tutorials like [this one](http://sourcey.com/beautiful-android-login-and-signup-screens-with-material-design/).

What really got me confused is that in all of the tutorials the ***Confirm/Reenter password*** part is skipped, so my question would be - is this the android standard? Do I need to add only one password field in my app?

I think that even facebook has only one field for password when users register a new account.

Comment: This you can do it by yourself, add two password field and then when a user pressed the button, then compare if the the passwords of two fields are the same.

Comment: if you use username as login, then you need that password confirmation. if you use email as login, then no need for that. as user, they can choose forget password to reset theirs

Comment: Thanks Bahramudun and @Tandyka. I do plan to login with the username, so is there any good example for comparing the two password fields. All of the examples I found skip the confirm password entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20953/why-should-we-ask-the-password-twice-during-registration) thread, you should no longer believe that your app needs having a password field twice; just once and along with a "Forgot Password?" button.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/518641/Show-hide-password-in-a-edit-text-view-password-ty) with my signup and login. It is a nice tutorial to show/hide password.